# Connecting LCD TFT shield to NodeMCU

Tags: esp8266, lcd, nodemcu, tft

I have the following screen:

[image: LCD]

I want to connect it to a NodeMCU device:

[image: NodeMCU]

I read somewhere that it is not possible. However, I am not interested in the touch ability nor the SD card. I just want to draw something on the screen.

Is it possible to make the connection in somehow?

Comment: This is well possible. The TFT just has a SPI interface (SCLK, MISO, MOSI, CS) with additional DC and BL lines (DC = Data/Command, BL = no idea). You need a driver library for the LCD. What driver chip does it say it has? Do you have a buy link for the module?

Comment: The device appears to be this https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.8inch_TFT_Touch_Shield

Comment: BL = Back Light

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The driver chip was identified by https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.8inch_TFT_Touch_Shield and https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/8/84/2.8inch-TFT-Touch-Shield-UserManual-EN.pdf as being the **HX8347D**.

At https://github.com/jshnaidman/UTFT_ESP8266_HX8347D there seems to be a library, with which you can use the `HX8347D` display type to instantiate a `UTFT` object, with which you can draw. You can build upon this [demo code](https://github.com/jshnaidman/UTFT_ESP8266_HX8347D/blob/master/examples/ESP8266/UTFT_Demo_320x240_Serial_HW/UTFT_Demo_320x240_Serial_HW.ino).

The connections for the SPI interface are detailed [here](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/spi/). BL (backlight) pin is detailed [here](https://github.com/jshnaidman/UTFT_ESP8266_HX8347D/blob/master/src/tft_drivers/hx8347d/initlcd.h). The pin number for the D/C pin must be given in the code in the constructor and can be chosen freely.

Other reference code (which you might have to port) are:

- [HX8347D by Majenko](https://github.com/DisplayCore/HX8347D)
- [Code from Watterott](https://github.com/watterott/Arduino-Libs/blob/master/MI0283QT2/MI0283QT2.cpp)